# How to perform a custom sort based on input values and Asc/Desc as user Input -Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, string-comparison

I am trying to arrive at a solution for a problem related to sorting.
The input is a list of values where each value in list is a list containing two `String` values {name,id}
An Example input list resembles

```
{{name99,id1},{name2,id2},{name36,id3}}
```

My requirement is to sort these based on both input sort condition and sort order.
If sort condition is "name", with *asc* as input order criteria, then
my output list should be:

```
{{name2,id2},{name36,id3},{name99,id1}}
```

If sort condition is "id", with *desc* as input order criteria, then
my output list should be:

```
{{name36,id3},{name2,id2},{name99,id1}}
```

The implementation that is done so far doesn't sort the strings as per expectation in place when I use compareTo

```
        List<String> sample1= Arrays.asList("name99","id1");
        List<String> sample2= Arrays.asList("name1","id12");
        List<String> sample3= Arrays.asList("name22","id99");
        List<String> sample4= Arrays.asList("name36","id5");
        List<String> sample5= Arrays.asList("name343","id3");
        List<List<String>> items=Arrays.asList(sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5);
        String sortOrderVal="asc";
        String sortParamVal="name";
        int sortParameter="name".equalsIgnoreCase(sortParamVal)?0:1;
        sortBasedonInput(items,sortOrderVal,sortParameter);

    }
    
    
    private static void sortBasedonInput(List<List<String>> items, String sortOrder, int sortParameter) {
        System.out.println("before sort: "+items);
            for(int j=0;j<items.size();j++) {
                for(int i=0;i<items.size()-1;i++) {
                    if(items.get(i).get(sortParameter).compareTo(items.get(i+1).get(sortParameter))>0) {
                        List<String> temp=items.get(i);
                        items.set(i,items.get(i+1));
                        items.set(i+1,temp);
                    }
                }}
            if("asc".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder))
                System.out.println(items);
            else {
                Collections.reverse(items);
                System.out.println(items);
            }
            
    }
```

Output for the implementation for name with asc order:
before sort:

```
[[name99, id1], [name1, id12], [name22, id99], [name36, id5], [name343, id3]]
```

After sort:

```
[[name1, id12], [name22, id99], [name343, id3], [name36, id5], [name99, id1]]
```

note: item with name343 comes before item with name36

Comment: Are you able to change it from a list of lists to a list of custom objects?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share your attempts so far even if they don't work yet.

Comment: @Eritrean I have updated with the approach I tried to sort them with sample output

Comment: ahhh. Well, if you want to implement a sorter for your Collection, you generally shouldnt be doing it manually with a nested for loop. You should just use the built-in utilities from Collection

Comment: @PotatoGod Are all your items prefixed with `name` and `id` and differ only in the numbers apended to th end? What shall the order look like if for example the list contains the names `Alex23`, `Robert23` and `Janet23` ?

Answer (score 3):

The following shows the comparators used for sorting, and then a generic method in order to use the comparator as well as whether the order should be in desc or asc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> item1 = Arrays.asList("name99","id1");
        List<String> item2 = Arrays.asList("name2","id2");
        List<String> item3 = Arrays.asList("name36","id3");
        List<List<String>> listOfLists = Arrays.asList(item1, item2, item3);
        
        Comparator<List<String>> nameComparator = (l1, l2) -> l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0));
        Comparator<List<String>> idComparator = (l1, l2) -> l1.get(1).compareTo(l2.get(1));
        //sort by name in asc
        listOfLists.sort(nameComparator);
        System.out.println(listOfLists);
        //instead of making a new comparator with l2 compared to l1, just call comparator.reversed()
        listOfLists.sort(nameComparator.reversed());
        System.out.println(listOfLists);
        //testing out generic method to pass list of lists, sort comparator and the ordering of the sort.
        sortListByComparatorAndOrder(listOfLists, idComparator, "DESC");
        System.out.println(listOfLists);
        
    }
    //generic method to sort a list 
    public static <T> void sortListByComparatorAndOrder(List<T> listToSort, Comparator<T> sorter, String order) {
        if (order.equals("ASC")) {
            listToSort.sort(sorter);
        }else if (order.equals("DESC")) {
            listToSort.sort(sorter.reversed());
        }
    }
```

output:

```
[[name2, id2], [name36, id3], [name99, id1]]
[[name99, id1], [name36, id3], [name2, id2]]
[[name36, id3], [name2, id2], [name99, id1]]
```

You could also use the following method which does not use generics, and follows your method signature:

```
public static void sortListByGivenIndexAndOrder(List<List<String>> listToSort, int index, String order) {
        Comparator<List<String>> indexComparator = (l1, l2) -> l1.get(index).compareTo(l2.get(index));
        if (order.equals("ASC")) {
            listToSort.sort(indexComparator);
        }else if (order.equals("DESC")) {
            listToSort.sort(indexComparator.reversed());
        }
    }
```

Special note:
I suspect that this logic might not be a good idea considering that there are integers in the name. while name2 comes before name36, name2 will NOT come before name16, so I think this might not be the best logic for a comparator.

IF the id are string representations of numbers ie "9" "10" and not a mix of alphabet and numbers "id9" "id10", you could instead parse the numbers from the string in order to avoid the issue mentioned above in the note. ie:

```
Comparator<List<String>> idComparator = (l1, l2) -> {
            Integer val1 = Integer.parseInt(l1.get(1));
            Integer val2 = Integer.parseInt(l2.get(1));
            return val1.compareTo(val2);
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache's org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair to model it. This should cover all 4 cases:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MutablePair<>("name99", "id1"));
list.add(new MutablePair<>("name2", "id2"));
list.add(new MutablePair<>("name36", "id3"));
    
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft));// name, asc
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft, Collections.reverseOrder()));// name, desc
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getRight)); // id, asc
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getRight, Collections.reverseOrder())); // id, desc
```

Answer (score 2):

For the given sample input, that is: all items are prefixed with `name` and `id` and only differ by the digits appended at the end, something like below should work:

- Create a function to remove all non digit charachters and parse to int
- create a comparotor and choose the right index to compare with from the given param
- reverse the sort order if needed

Code:

```
private static void sortBasedonInput(List<List<String>> items, String sortOrder, int sortParameter) {

    Function<String,Integer> func = str -> Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
    Comparator<List<String>> sortBy = Comparator.comparingInt(list -> func.apply(list.get(sortParameter)));
    if (sortOrder.equals("desc")){
        sortBy = sortBy.reversed();
    }
    items.sort(sortBy);
}
```